# Which of $(-\infty,\infty]$ and $[-\infty,\infty]$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Is it correct to say that $(-\infty,\infty]$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$? or it is $[-\infty,\infty]$? (considering standard topology).

Would you please provide some explanation or better a rigorous mathematical proof for your answer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Neither is homeomorphic to $S^1$. $(-\infty,\infty]$ is not compact, while $S^1$ is, so they cannot be homeomorphic. $[-\infty,\infty]$ is compact, being homeomorphic to $[0,1]$, but removing any one point of $\Bbb R$ from $[-\infty,\infty]$ disconnects it, while removing one point from $S^1$ does not disconnect $S^1$, so they are not homeomorphic either.

Comment: As I read "one-point compactification of the plane is homeomorphic to the sphere, $S^2$" in the book i.e. $S^2\cong \mathbb R^2 \cup {\{\infty}\}$, I thought the mentioned question. Is it possible to find some set $X$ such that $\mathbb R \cup X$ be homeomorphic to the sphere, $S^1$"?

Comment: @AlphaE: Yes: $S^1$ is homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of $\Bbb R$. Instead of adding a point at each end of $\Bbb R$, add one new point and ‘bend’ $\Bbb R$ around so that the new point is at both ends.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand 'where' this new point is located. Any point has meaning if the set of containing it exists (?); I mean, if $S^1\cong \mathbb R \cup {\{\infty}\}$ so there must be a set $X$ such that ${\{\infty}\}$ (or any other 'name' for the new point) $\in X$, and if so what is this $X$? Thank you.

Comment: @AlphaE: Just let $p$ be any object not in $\Bbb R$, and let $X=\Bbb R\cup\{p\}$. Then say that a set $U\subseteq X$ is a nbhd of $p$ iff there is an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $(-\infty,n)\cup\{p\}\cup(n,\infty)\subseteq U$.

Answer (score 1):

If $(-\infty,+\infty]$ is construed as a mere set rather than as a topological space, then it's not homeomorphic to anything including itself.  Now lets add a topology: a basic open neighborhood of a point other than $+\infty$ is an open interval containing that point; a basic open neighborhood of $+\infty$ is a set of the form $(a,+\infty]\cup (-\infty,b)$; and an open set is the union of any collection of these "basic" open sets.  *That* space is homeomorphic to a circle, and one homeomorphism is this:
$$
p(t) = \left( \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \frac{2t}{1+t^2} \right). \tag 1
$$
The point $p(t)$ is on the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ and we consider $p(+\infty)$ to be $\lim\limits_{t\to+\infty} p(t) = (-1,0)$.

But that is perhaps not the most usual topology on the set $(-\infty,+\infty]$.  In the order topology, one can define basic open sets as above except that a basic open neighborhood of $+\infty$ would be of the form $(a,+\infty]$.

But if you're going to do things according to $(1)$ above, it is better not to distinguish between two objects $\pm\infty$, but rather to have just one $\infty$ that is at both ends of the line.  Then one can define, for example, $\tan(\pi/2)$ to be $\infty$ and that makes it a continuous function, and likewise every rational function becomes continuous at points where it has vertical asymptotes and at $\infty$/

Comment: Is $(a,+\infty]\cup (-\infty,b)$ compact? and, is it homoemorphic to $(c,d)$? Thank you.

Comment: It is homeomorphic to $(c,d)$, and it may be worth figuring out what a homeomorphism is in this case.  Do you know the Heine-Borel theorem? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes I know Heine-Borel theorem if you mean equivalence of compactness and closed&bounded-ness (in standard topology and the standard metric). I think some tangent function including $\frac{\pi}{2}$ in $(c,d)$ can be a homeomorphism (?) ; but the other answer (Brian M. Scott) said $(-\infty,\infty]$ is not compact! (?)

Comment: ... I am new to topology, so I am a little confused! sorry

Comment: The tangent function from $\mathbb R/\pi$ to $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ is indeed a homeomorphism. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

Related to some of the comments, you might be interested to know that $(-\infty,\infty]$ in the [cyclic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_order) topology is homeomorphic to $S^1$. The cyclic order topology is coarser than the corresponding linear order topology, in this case strictly coarser.